# c++ regex, passing equivalent string parameters, but receiving different outputs

Tags: c++, regex, recursion

We are receiving quite an unusual error. Our program attempts to calculate derivatives using regular expressions and recursion.

From our file input, we used regex to determine the derivative rule that we need to apply. Using smatch, we are able to parse different parts of our string equation.

Our error appears when our program attempts to calculate the derivative for "(x^2)+(x)". Smatch parses "x^2" and "x" from this equation and recursively calls the derivative function using these two strings as parameters. However, our output is missing the derivative of "x".

Input:

```
(x^2)+(x)
```

Call:

```
return derivative(s[1].str()) + "+" + derivative(s[2].str());
```

Output:

```
2x^1*1+
```

However, if we pass:

```
return derivative(s[1].str()) + "+" + derivative("x");
```

Then, the output becomes:

```
2x^1*1+1
```

We also checked if (s[2].str() == "x"), and this is true. Why are we getting different outputs from the same input?

Equations.txt:

```
7
x
5x
x^3
(x^2)+(x)
```

main.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <cmath>
#include <queue>
#include <stack>
#include <regex>
#include <vector>
#include <iterator>
#include <map>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

/*****************************************************************/

class ReadFile
{
private:
    ifstream infile;
    queue<string> input;
public:
    ReadFile(string filename)
    {
        infile.open(filename);
        if(!infile)
            cerr << "Unable to open file\n";
        string temp;
        while(!infile.eof())
        {
            getline(infile, temp);
            input.push(temp);
        }
    }
    string getFront()
    {
        string temp = input.front();
        input.pop();
        return temp;
    }
    bool isEmpty() { return input.empty(); }
};

/*****************************************************************/

class Simplifier
{
private:
    string exp;
public:
    Simplifier(string ex): exp(ex) {}

};

/*****************************************************************/


class ExpressionAnalyzer
{
    string expression;
    map<string, regex> rules;
    smatch s;
public:
    ExpressionAnalyzer()
    {
        rules["con"] = "([[:d:]]+)";
        rules["xxx"] = "(x|\\(x\\))";
        rules["cof"] = "([[:d:]]+)(.*)";
        rules["pow"] = "(.*)[^]([[:d:]]+)";
        rules["add"] = "\\((.*)\\)[+]\\((.*)\\)";
    }

    string derivative(string str)
    {
        s = generateSmatch(str);
        if(regex_match(str, rules["con"]))
            return "0";
        else if (regex_match(str, rules["xxx"]))
            return "1";
        else if (regex_match(str, rules["cof"]))
            return s[1].str() + "*" + derivative(s[2].str());
        else if (regex_match(str, rules["pow"]))
            return s[2].str() + s[1].str() + "^" + to_string(stoi(s[2].str()) - 1) + "*" + derivative(s[1].str());
        else if (regex_match(str, rules["add"])) {
             cout << "s[1]: " << s[1].str() << ", s[2]: " << s[2].str() << endl;
            return derivative(s[1].str()) + "+" + derivative(s[2].str());}
        return "";
    }

    smatch generateSmatch(string str)
    {
        smatch s;
        map<string, regex>::iterator it;
        for(it = rules.begin(); it != rules.end(); it++)
        {
            if(regex_match(str, s, it->second))
            {
                return s;
            }
        }
        return s;
    }
};

/*****************************************************************/

int main()
{
    ReadFile test("Equations.txt");

    string s = test.getFront();
    ExpressionAnalyzer e;
    cout << e.derivative(s) << endl;

}
```

Comment: I'm not sure what the actual problem is, but executing your code on ideone yields these results: `e.derivative("(x)")` returns `1` (that works) `e.derivative("(x^2)")` returns an empty string and `e.derivative("(x^2)+(x)")` returns 1+1. I guess something with your recursion is broken. I would suggest to try to generate only the specific smatch you need inside the if instead of looping over all possibilities and then using an if. I think that would make errors more obvious.

Comment: I got different results depending of clang/gcc...

Answer (score 0):

I'm still not sure what happens exactly here. To know more, use a debugger, step through your program and check every variable after each step.
Or add a lot more debug-output to be sure you know at which point of the recursion your program fails.

However by getting rid of the loop (and the entire `generateSmatch()`-function), i was able to get your code to work (nearly, see below).
Note that there might be a cleaner solution, since a lot of code is repeated inside the if-statement, but this one works and i'll leave prettifying up to you.
Also note that this might be a partial solution only, since i did not test the file-loading part. So be sure to get rid of extra `\n` and similar before calling this function.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <cmath>
#include <queue>
#include <stack>
#include <regex>
#include <vector>
#include <iterator>
#include <map>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

/*****************************************************************/


class ExpressionAnalyzer
{
    string expression;
    map<string, regex> rules;
public:
    ExpressionAnalyzer()
    {
        rules["con"] = "([[:d:]]+)";
        rules["xxx"] = "(x|\\(x\\))";
        rules["cof"] = "([[:d:]]+)(.*)";
        rules["pow"] = "(.*)[^]([[:d:]]+)";
        rules["add"] = "\\((.*)\\)[+]\\((.*)\\)";
    }

    string derivative(string str)
    {
        cout << "call with: " << str << endl;
        if(regex_match(str, rules["con"])){
            cout << "const!" << endl;
            return "0";
            }
        else if (regex_match(str, rules["xxx"])){
            cout << "xxx!" << endl;
            return "1";
        }
        else if (regex_match(str, rules["cof"])){
            cout << "cof!" << endl;
            smatch s;
            regex_match(str, s, rules["cof"]);
             cout << "s[1]: " << s[1].str() << ", s[2]: " << s[2].str() << endl;
            return s[1].str() + "*" + derivative(s[2].str());
            }
        else if (regex_match(str, rules["pow"])){
            cout << "pow!" << endl;
            smatch s;
            regex_match(str, s, rules["pow"]);
             cout << "s[1]: " << s[1].str() << ", s[2]: " << s[2].str() << endl;
            return s[2].str() + s[1].str() + "^" + to_string(stoi(s[2].str()) - 1) + "*" + derivative(s[1].str());
        }
        else if (regex_match(str, rules["add"])) {
            cout << "add!" << endl;
            smatch s;
            regex_match(str, s, rules["add"]);
             cout << "s[1]: " << s[1].str() << ", s[2]: " << s[2].str() << endl;
            return derivative(s[1].str()) + "+" + derivative(s[2].str());}
        else{
            cout << "not recognized!" << endl;
            return "";
        }
    }

};

/*****************************************************************/

int main()
{
    ExpressionAnalyzer e;
    cout << e.derivative("(x)") << endl;
    cout << e.derivative("(x^2)") << endl;
    cout << e.derivative("x^2") << endl;
    cout << e.derivative("(x^2)+(x)") << endl;

}
```

Output:

```
call with: (x)
xxx!
1                      <-result
call with: (x^2)
not recognized!
                       <-result (parantheses were not simplified away yet)
call with: x^2
pow!
s[1]: x, s[2]: 2
call with: x           <- recursion
xxx!
2x^1*1                 <-result (without parantheses: working)
call with: (x^2)+(x)
add!
s[1]: x^2, s[2]: x
call with: x           <- recursion
xxx!
call with: x^2         <- recursion
pow!
s[1]: x, s[2]: 2
call with: x           <- recursion lvl 2
xxx!
2x^1*1+1               <- result (YAY!)
```

I left the debug-output on purpose, maybe it helps to see that sometimes more detailed output helps to see whats going on internally.

Answer (score 0):

`s` is a member, and in your recursive fonction you change it

```
s = generateSmatch(str);
```

Turn it as local variable to get expected result:

```
string derivative(string str)
{
    smatch s;
    if(regex_match(str, s, rules["con"]))
        return "0";
    else if (regex_match(str, s, rules["xxx"]))
        return "1";
    else if (regex_match(str, s, rules["cof"]))
        return s[1].str() + "*" + derivative(s[2].str());
    else if (regex_match(str, s, rules["pow"]))
        return s[2].str() + s[1].str() + "^" + to_string(stoi(s[2].str()) - 1) + "*" + derivative(s[1].str());
    else if (regex_match(str, s, rules["add"])) {
         cout << "s[1]: " << s[1].str() << ", s[2]: " << s[2].str() << endl;
        return derivative(s[1].str()) + "+" + derivative(s[2].str());}
    return "";
}
```